# Creating executable in c++ which returns int array

Tags: c++

I want my C++ executable to return int array.

```
int* main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    return *a;
}
```

This will give `error: '::main' must return 'int'`.
Is there other way to do this?

Comment: You can't (limitation by both the basic OS concept AND C/C++ standard). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `int main(int argc,char **argv)` is the calling convention for commands from a shell. The shell expects an int value return code... Who is expecting an array from you?

Comment: The question is - why would you want this?

Comment: I want to execute one binary which will give me int array some how and I want to process it in different machine.

Comment: You can use standard input/output to pass data to other programs

Comment: @user3153014, write results to file or to stdout (which, in turn, can also be redirected to a file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ main must indeed return an int. It is the error code of the program. 0 if everything went well, a positive number otherwise.

If you want to display an array of int. you can use `<iostream>`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
       std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}
```

You can also choose to write to a file that is going to be read by another program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open ("out.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
       myfile << a[i] << std::endl;
   myfile.close()
}
```

then in the other program

```
   std::vector<int> a;
   ifstream myfile;
   myfile.open ("out.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
       int ai;
       myfile >> ai;
       a.push_back(ai);
   }
   myfile.close()
```

Comment: I want to process it further

Comment: Then there are several possibilities. Parse the output of this program, write to a file, write to a socket.

Comment: Why the downvote ? I did not compilecheck the code i posted. if there is a typo it is worth mentioning it...

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this. The return type of the `main` function normally indicates only an error code. To output the result of some computation, write your array to a file.

For example:

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::ofstream ofs("data.tsv");
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        ofs << a[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

main is a special function and C++ standard is specific about its signature:

**C++ Standard n3337 3.6.1**

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the
> designated start of the program. It is implementation-defined whether
> a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
> function. [ Note: In a freestanding environment, start-up and
> termination is implementation-defined; start- up contains the
> execution of constructors for objects of namespace scope with static
> storage duration; termination contains the execution of destructors
> for objects with static storage duration. — end note ]
>
> An
> implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function
> shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but
> otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations
> shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> int main() { /*
> ...
> */ }
>
> and
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ...
> */ }

---

> Is there other way to do this?

Print to a file or display using stream:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}
```

or:

```
#include <algorithm>

int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::copy( a, a + 8, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout,", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very explicit. `main`must return an `int`, not an array. It is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this. According to the C++ standard, main() has to return `int`.
See section 3.6.1.2 of the standard:

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. 
>      This function shall not be overloaded. 
>      It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the signature of the main method.  All code that invokes a process uses the same interface with a single int returned - how would you expect to retrieve these extra ints in whatever code is invoking the process?

However - if you need to combine multiple pieces of information, you can still encode them into a single int value.  For example you could interpret the decimal digits separately, allowing you to return ten or more values each taking values from 0-9.  Or for a different example, you may combine 32 binary flags to make up the integer value.  Whether this is useful depends on your use case.